# Trying to show element based on user selection

Tags: reactjs, onclick, selection, show-hide

Here I have my div that contains Two Options ["Book" , "prices"] .
My goal is when the user select the Book option it would show the element for the book , same thing for the price one too .

here is my code :

```
const BooksandPrices = props => {
    const option =["Book" , "Prices"]
    return (
        <div>
                    {option.map((option) => (
                        <div
                            className='bp'
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                {option == 'Book' && <PriceTable  />}
                                {option == 'Prices' && <BookTable  />}
                            }}
                        >
                            {option}
                            </div>
                    ))}
        </div>
    )
}

return (

<BooksandPrices />

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my presumption is correct that  and  are the elements for each respective option, then you'll want to move them outside of the option.map and initialize a state variable to control which element is displayed

```
const BooksandPrices = props => {
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState();
    const option =["Book" , "Prices"]
    return (
        <div>
                    {option.map((option) => (
                        <div
                          className='bp'
                          onClick={() => setSelectedOption(option)}
                        >
                            {option}
                            </div>
                    ))}
                    {selectedOption == 'Book' && <PriceTable  />}
                    {selectedOption == 'Prices' && <BookTable  />}
        </div>
    )
}

return (

<BooksandPrices />

)
```

Comment: Tysm it worked !!1

Answer (score 0):

React Hooks could solve this, you just need to add useState hook.
Also keep in mind that you should to add key attribute when you loop through an array.

```js
const BooksandPrices = props => {
        const option =["Book" , "Prices"];
        const [checkedOption, setCheckedOption] = useState("Book");
        return (
            <div>
                        {option.map((option, idx) => (
                            <div
                                className='bp'
                                onClick={()=>setCheckedOption(option)}
                                key={idx}
                            >
                            {option}
                           
                     
                                   
      
                                </div>
                        ))}
                         <div>
                            {checkedOption === 'Book' ? <BookTable  />:<PriceTable /> }
                            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```